# How do I pattern match on different types?

Tags: haskell

```
data Test = [Int] | Int

foobar :: Test -> Int
```

What if I wanted something like foobar [1,2,3] = 1 and foobar 1 = 1. In erlang it would be

```
foobar(X) when is_list(X) -> hd(X);
foobar(X) -> X.
```

Comment: Do you have a particular use case for this? Or are you just curious? (Not that there's anything wrong curiosity!) To get the behavior you're asking for you have to fight the type system a little bit, so there's probably a more haskell-y way to solve whatever problem you're working on.

Comment: Just curious. I've come across a few places where I would like to have something like this. I have not made anything useful yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, your data-declaration is invalid. In Haskell, you have to start a data-declaration with a *data-constructor*, that is later matched upon. For instance, your type `Test` would be written

```
data Test = TLst [Int] | TInt Int
```

Now you can simply match on the type-constructor; it's field is a list or an int, depending on which constructor you match:

```
foobar :: Test -> Int
foobar (TLst (x:xs)) = x
foobar (TLst [])     = error "empty list passed to foobar"
foobar (TInt x)      = x
```

Comment: You mean "data constructor" when you say "type constructor".

Answer (score 7):

The other approach to this is to use a typeclass, like so:

```
class Test a where 
    foobar a -> Int

instance Test Int where
    foobar x = x

instance Test [Int] where
    foobar [] = error "Empty list"
    foobar (x:_) = x
```

The pattern matching is implicit here--the type passed to foobar determines which instance we choose.

But you probably don't want to be doing this sort of thing unless there's a symmetry in your problem that makes it sensible to think of Int and [Int] as two examples of the same sort of thing. The better your types match the problem you're solving, the more the typechecker can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, this is not valid Haskell syntax:

```
data Test = [Int] | Int   -- this doesn't work
```

The alternatives require their own constructors. So this is valid:

```
data Test = TestA [Int] | TestB Int
```

Then you can pattern match like this:

```
foobar :: Test -> Int
foobar (TestA listOfInt) = length listOfInt
foobar (TestB int)       = int
```